# Audio driver issue with Windows dual boot

Tags: sound, microphone

Hello everybody,
                       I recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 dual boot on my existing Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit) Samsung laptop.The lap uses Realtek Audio Drivers. The audio (both laptop speakers and output in the earphone) works perfectly in Ubuntu, but the earphone does not work in Windows 7. The speakers work perfect in both the OS s. Before this, everything was normal in Windows7. I googled it quite a bit for the the last couple of days.

Some things I have found and tested are

```
When I shutdown the laptop and just remove the battery (to reset the power connection) and boot directly into Windows, everything works perfect. But when I boot into Ubuntu first and then to Windows no output in the earphone.
When I restart from Ubuntu or Windows and boot into Windows first, same problem persists.
I have also updated all the drivers (both Realtek and from Samsung). That does not solve either.
```

I have tried everything that I found ,but still have the problem.

Would be glad if any of you could help me out.
Do ask me for more details if you require any.

Thanks and Regards
Shree

PS.. I am pretty sure no volume mixers are muted, and speakers are the default playback devices and microphone is the default recording device. In fact I can record any time on Windows but it is just that I cannot hear audio playback in the earphone. And sorry for keeping it a bit long.

Comment: Oh wow, this is eerily similar to the realtek 8168/8169 ethernet driver problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1436667&p=10471186#post10471186 but in reverse. Try to bug realtek and ask if there's something you can try in windows to "kick" the hardware?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I aam a newbie to Ubuntu. Can you please explain anything you know that would be helpful? Because I don find much information on the link you provided..